# Vehicle Tracking with MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, tracking

I have a database of vehicle data and would like to view it on a live updating map. Does anyone have any free, simple web solutions that connect with mySQL?

I'd like the software to be a live updating map, the information I have on the vehicles (buses) is their location, speed and direction along with their route number so I'd be good to see most or all of this information displayed. I'd like to be able to view them on a map and have coloured pins per speed range to identify delay hotspots. If possible I'd like to view its location history too.

Privacy-wise, JS is fine as is external assets; its a public API I'm getting the data from so theres no secrets there.

Comment: MySql is on your server, but you speak off JS. Do you have any preference for a client or server side solution?

Comment: I'd prefer a client side solution, just for ease of installation and to prevent complications

Comment: In general (as I am sure you know), server side is more secure & client side is more flexible. If you *do* go client side, you will have to pull the MySql data from your server with AJAX. Do you prefer Google Maps or Open Street Maps? Plain JS or Angaulr JS? I recommend [ng-map](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) for Angualr. Alan is very helpful, and actively looks for related questions on S.O